# run a C program at startup [Red Pitaya]

Tags: c

I have a C program that needs to run when I turn on my machine (Red Pitaya).
the beginning of the program presented here:

```
//my_test program

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "redpitaya/rp.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int jj=1;

while(1) {

printf("Ready for experiment number %i\n",jj);

    int i, D;
    int32_t TrigDly;
```

and so on...

the program is executable with a run.sh file called `uri_test.sh`, that contains the following:

```
cat /opt/redpitaya/fpga/fpga_0.94.bit>/dev/xdevcfg
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/redpitaya/lib ./my_test
```

both files are located in a directory under /root. the program is working perfectly when run manually on PuTTY terminal-

```
/RedPitaya/Examples/C/Uri# ./my_test
```

or

```
/RedPitaya/Examples/C/Uri# ./uri_test.sh
```

I tried to follow the solution presented here :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup

without success. 
any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: C? C#? Neither are scripts. Or the mysterious #C is?

Comment: You should show the script in your question. I won't call a C or C# source file a script (and you need also to show how exactly you have compiled it). So **edit your question** (source code lines need to be prefixed by four spaces) to improve it a lot

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:c], it's a ubuntu specific question. Please read about [systemd services](http://www.devdungeon.com/content/creating-systemd-service-files). Also, there are no [tag:c] scripts, [tag:c] is a compiled language. And a "*startup*" program can be in principle, any executable file, whether it's a shell script or a compiled c program. Also, C# if that's what you mean is a Windows specific language, it can work on linux AFAIK but it's not very common to see C# programs on linux.

Comment: C is not a scripting language, so can't be. I did not find a tag for "#C". Is that some new scripting variant of C#? Some replacement for VBA?

Comment: @Olaf: With [TinyC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) compiler, you can (or could) write a script in C (starting with `#!/usr/bin/tcc -run`..) but of course I don't recommend doing that

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It still would be a program, as much as Python is a full programing language. The difference is whether the code is stand-along (or just run by the interpreter) or loaded for a larger program. Hence Sconstruct files for SCons are scripts, despite being Python code, while SCOns itself is a program.

Comment: @Olaf: It  depends upon how you define a script (or a scripting language). YMMV. For example, I believe that both [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and [scsh](https://scsh.net/) are used as scripting language (but the later is much closer to what you call a programming language)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, but the standalone criterion with only a runtime sounds reasonable. Even when compiled most languages have some runtime, including C (crt). For interpreted languages, that would be the interpreter.

Comment: And what about SBCL ?

Comment: Idk this language. If the criterionms apply, it might be. Oh, I forgot the most important: Turing-completeness, of course. I'm open for a better def, though. I'm just cery clear about C and Python, Ruby, etc. being PLs.

Comment: Even with the edit, the question remains unclear. Perhaps editing your [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) with a `@reboot` entry could be enough. BTW, I would recommend using [syslog](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) in your C program (because its *stdout* is likely to be lost, e.g. to `/dev/null` ....). Read also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ to get a better understanding

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to have a program running at startup, and it depends upon your [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) subsystem (are you using [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) or a SysV-style init?).

BTW, a source program in C is not a [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) and you generally compile it (using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) into some [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable). In your case, you probably want to set up its [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) at build time (in particular to avoid the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` madness), perhaps by passing something like `-Wl,-rpath,/opt/redpitaya/lib` to your linking `gcc` command.

Perhaps a  [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry with `@reboot`  could be enough.

Whatever way you are starting your program at startup time, it generally is the case that its *stdin*, *stdout*, *stderr* streams are redirected (e.g. to `/dev/null`, see [null(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html)) or not available. So it is likely that your `printf` output go nowhere. You might redirect stdout in your script, and I would recommend using [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) in your C program, and [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) in your shell script (then look also into some `*.log` file under `/var/log/`). BTW, its environment is not the same as in some interactive shell (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)...), so your program is probably failing very early (perhaps at dynamic linking time, see [ld-linux.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html), since  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` might not be set to what you want it to be...).

You should consider handing program arguments in your C program (perhaps with [getopt_long(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt_long.3.html)) and might perhaps have some option (e.g. `--daemonize`)  which would call [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html).

You certainly should read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) or something similar.

I recommend to first be able to successfully build then run some "hello-world" like program at startup which uses [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html). Later on, you could improve that program to make it work with your Red Pitaya thing.